# the 'read-only' objects in generics type with wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, readonly, diamond-operator

Consider the following code (the two questions are inside the code):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tree<T> {
    private T info;
    private List<Tree<? extends T>> children = new ArrayList<Tree<? extends T>>();

    public Tree<? extends T> getChildren(int n) {
        return children.get(n);
    }

    public void addChildren(Tree<? extends T> children) {
        this.children.add(children);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tree<?> b2; // so b2 is a reference of a Tree of unknown type
        b2 = new Tree<Number>(); /* to allow b2 to call addChildren() with Tree<? extends Number> aguments */
        b2.addChildren(new Tree<Number>()); // 1) why it doesn't work ?
        b2.addChildren(new Tree<Integer>()); // neither does this one!
        b2.addChildren(new Tree<>()); // 2) but with diamond <> it works ?
    }
}
```

1. Why does `b2.addChildren(new Tree<Number>())` not work?
2. But it works with diamond <> `b2.addChildren(new Tree<>())`. Which type list the compiler uses inside the diamond <>?

Comment: None of the three `addChildren` calls here would work. And the `Tree<>` means `Tree<Object>` in this context. Read the [generics guidelines trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) to understand why. All this assuming, you made a typo with `Arbre`.

Comment: sorry but I made a mistake. there is no Arbre type. I already change the word Arbre by Tree, if you would reread the code. thanks!

Comment: @mystarrocks: `Tree<>` does NOT mean `Tree<Object>`

Comment: @newacct, I didn't say it always does - it's just in this context. A `new Tree<>` is a `Tree<Object>` if the reference type is `Tree<?>`, i.e `Tree<?> tree = new Tree<>()`. Here `tree` IS a `Tree<Object>`. That said, such an explicit assignment (as opposed to method params) makes no sense.

Comment: @mystarrocks: No it is not. The type of the parameter is not `Tree<?>`. It is `Tree<? extends T>` for some unknown `T`. Passing `new Tree<Object>()` would be illegal. Therefore, `new Tree<>()` is NOT `new Tree<Object>()`.

Comment: @newacct are you saying `Tree<?> tree = new Tree<>()` is illegal?! It surely isn't? Nor is `Tree<?> tree = new Tree<Object>()`.

Comment: @mystarrocks: `Tree<?> tree = new Tree<Object>();` is perfectly legal. `Tree<? extends T> tree = new Tree<Object>();` is illegal when `T` is not `Object`. The parameter of the method `addChildren` is `Tree<? extends T>`.

Comment: Exactly and that's why the line throws an error. To see how `Tree<?> tree = new Tree<>()` results in a `Tree<Object>`, hover over the line `b2.addChildren(new Tree<>());` and read the error message. It would read: "The method addChildren(Tree<? extends capture#4-of ?>) in the type Tree<capture#4-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Tree<Object>)" and rightly so.

Comment: @mystarrocks: You forgot to use `@` when replying to comments. Just because your compiler produces an error does not mean it should produce an error.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you have declared `b2` to have a type of `Tree<?>`.

The problem is clearer if you rewrite your main method as two methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(new Tree<Number>());
}

private static void test(Tree<?> b2) {
    // "<?>" means we don't know what the generic type of b2 is, so
    // the compiler can't possibly know if it's safe to add any type
    // of children...

    b2.addChildren(new Tree<Number>()); // 1) why it doesn't work ?
    b2.addChildren(new Tree<Integer>()); // neither does this one!
    b2.addChildren(new Tree<>()); // 2) but with diamond <> it works ?
}
```

Even though you *created* a `new Tree<Number>()`, you are immediately discarding that information.  Your code is only remembering that `b2` contains some unknown type of Tree, since `Tree<?>` means "some type of Tree but I don't know what type."

Since we don't know what the Tree's type is, how do we know if it's safe to call `addChildren(new Tree<Number>())`, or `new Tree<Integer>()` or `new Tree<String>()` or `new Tree<JTable>()`?  The compiler has no idea.  You may remember what you put in there, but the type of `b2` doesn't carry that information, so the compiler doesn't have any way to know.

Comment: I understand your explanation and agree with you : since b2 is a Tree of unknown type reference, calling addChildren() doesn't make no sense. thing is, the Tree type of addChildren()'s argument is related to the Tree type of b2, the object who calls, and must be concretely known so we can call the method. However, my question still why the compiler doesn't refuse the call b2.addChildren(new Tree<>()) using diamond in my first code ?? it means that the compiler determines the type argument from the context! So what is this type ??

Comment: Yes, the compiler determines the type from the context.  Since the context is `Tree<?>`, there isn't anything the compiler can infer.